# Is there a word that describe both parents of me and my spouse?

Tags: word-request

Is there a word that could describe both my parents and my spouse's parents, instead of saying "my parents and my spouse parents"?

For example,

> **My parents and my spouse parents** (Replacement??) are going together for this pilgrimage tour.

Comment: Is there a nice simple word in your language?  what is it and what does a bilingual dictionary translate that word as?

Comment: "My parents and my parents-in-law"

Comment: My spouse's and my parents, or, if it is already clear that the married couple are being discussed 'our parents'.

Comment: "My son's grandparents".

Comment: "Both sets of parents"

Comment: @KateBunting Or "and in-laws". Without qualification, "in-laws" usually means "parents-in-laws"

Answer (score 16):

How about "Our parents are going together for this pilgrimage tour" (with context supplying that "our" is yourself and spouse).

Or "My wife's parents are going with mine on the pilgrimage tour".

I am not aware of any single relationship word that includes both natural and parents-in-law.

Comment: *"Our parents"* works even without *"together"*, as *"Our parents"* can only mean *"The parents of us"* (+1 anyway)

Comment: I took the "together" to mean that they are going as a linked group and not just both sets of parents happening to be traveling the same route.

Comment: "Together" is already the default assumption for most contexts, especially for a group activity like a tour, so as @abligh says this sentence is fine without being explicit.  If you said "our parents are all going to get vaccinated next week", the "all" suggests that you're talking about each one separately and needed an extra word to collect them in your phrasing, not necessarily as one group.  It would be ambiguous if you said "our parents are going to get vaccinated next week", but people would probably guess from context that it was separate appointments, or at least separate pairs.

Comment: @abligh: "Together" implies that they are not already an implicit unit. This could be e.g. divorced parents, parents who are commonly expected to individually attend events, or in this case, different households who both happen to be parents of the couple in question. Furthermore, "together" implies travelling as a single group, whereas "our parents are going to ..." can mean they are travelling individually.

Comment: "Our parents", to me, implies only one set of parents and that the speakers are siblings.

Answer (score 9):

There's no single word.  Your spouse's parents are your mother-in-law and father-in-law.  And while "in-laws" means all of your spouse's family, it is probably understandable to say:

> My parents and in-laws are going...

It would be more natural to say "my wife's parents" (if your spouse is female) or "my husband's parents" as "spouse" tends to be limited to situations where the speaker doesn't know the person's gender. So it is natural to rearrange a little and say:

> My parent's are going on a pilgrimage tour with my wife's parents.

There is also no simple word to describe the relationship between the two sets of parents.  There is no common word that means "a parent of the spouse of my child".

Comment: Yiddish has a word that comes close: http://www.jewishhumorcentral.com/2014/11/yiddishology-untranslatable-yiddish.html

Comment: For what it's worth, in AmEn at least, I've probably never understood "in-laws" to be the entire other side. It's almost always used to describe the spouse's parents. (obviously context can refer to everyone, but I have seldom if ever heard it used that way colloquially).

Answer (score 2):

Our parents or our in-laws would both work.  In-laws might imply a bit more than just the 4 of them, but not so strongly that anyone would be shocked to discover that it was just the 6 of you going on the trip.

Which leads to an even better word, if you have any children: the grandparents.

Answer (score 0):

If you already have children then they are "**grandparents of our children**" if you really need to use one single expression